# OpenGL 3 program blank screen

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I've been converting some of my old code to OpenGL 3, and I've gotten most of it working. All the VAOs, VBOs, etc. are working fine, as verified by an OpenGL debugging program, and my shaders compile just fine, but nothing appears on the screen other than my clear color. I think all my matrices should be fine, although I'm not sure if the projection matrix is supposed to convert negative Z-coordinates to positive ones; every code sample I've tried produces such a matrix. Here are my shaders:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 projection;

in vec4 position;
in vec4 normal;
in vec4 texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * modelview * position;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

My code is complex, so I'll just post a modified, commented version of the glIntercept call log, which should have all the relevant calls:

```
    //Create shaders
glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)=1 
glShaderSource(1,1,vertShaderText,vertShaderTextLen)
glCompileShader(1)
glGetShaderiv(1,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,buf)
glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)=2 
glShaderSource(2,1,fragShaderText,fragShaderTextLen)
glCompileShader(2)
glGetShaderiv(2,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,buf)
glCreateProgram()=3 
glAttachShader(3,1)
glAttachShader(3,2)
glLinkProgram(3)
glGetProgramiv(3,GL_LINK_STATUS,buf)
//Find uniform/attribute locations
//Extra glUseProgram() calls are for safety.
glGetUniformLocation(3,"modelview")=0 
glUseProgram(3)
glGetUniformLocation(3,"projection")=1 
glUseProgram(3)
glGetAttribLocation(3,"position")=0 
glUseProgram(3)
glGetAttribLocation(3,"normal")=-1 
glUseProgram(3)
glGetAttribLocation(3,"texCoord")=-1
//Create a texture; probably irrelevant to this code
glGenTextures(1,texId)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,256,256,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texData)
glGenTextures(1,01DD275C)
//Create VAO, VBO
glGenVertexArrays(1,vaoId)
glBindVertexArray(1)
glGenBuffers(1,bufId)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,1)
//Redundant call; actual data set later
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,00000000,GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glGenBuffers(1,indexBufId)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,4)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,00000000,GL_STATIC_DRAW)

//Set up buffer data
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,4)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,96,indexData,GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,1)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 48,01DC3D00,GL_STATIC_DRAW)

//Start drawing
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glUseProgram(3)
glUseProgram(3)
//Modelview
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelviewLocation,1,false,[1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,-6.000000,1.000000])
glUseProgram(3)
//Projection
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLocation,1,false,[0.200000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.150000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,-1.000200,-1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,-0.200020,0.000000])
//Bind VAO, VBOs, and attribute positions
glBindVertexArray(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,1)
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation,3,GL_FLOAT,false,12,00000000)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,4)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,24,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,00000000) GLSL=3  Textures[ (0,2) ]
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
```

I've got a plane facing directly into the camera, but it doesn't show up at all. All I see is the clear color. Culling and depth test are off.

Comment: I've done some more debugging work; using AMD's GPUPerfStudio, I can verify that the primitives are being sent properly by glDrawElements, but they never reach the screen. I'm not sure what can be stopping them from reaching it; I've done my best to verify all my matrices and even tried using an identity projection matrix; nothing seems to work.

Comment: From what I can see the fragment shader would only show red pixels. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my problem was in my initialization code. I had uninitialized variables that were being passed to glViewport, giving me a 0x0 viewport.

Answer (score 0):

When passing uniforms to a shader i've used glGetUniformLocation() in the following way:

```
myUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "myUniform")
glUniform1f(myUniformLocation, variable_value)
```

Comment: That's basically the form I'm using; by the time I got to that point in editing the call trace, I had stopped replacing the traced values with descriptive variable names. I should probably fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your log does not show any `glEnableVertexAttribArray` call. Did you forget that?

Comment: It looks like it wasn't called in the first frame, but it was called in every frame after that. I've fixed that; still no luck.